# Navigation menu collapsed after clicking toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I always use bootstrap's default navigation toggle for responsive view, this time I tried overlay menu,

Everything works fine here.

**My problem is** when the screen size is below 767px the toggle bar appears, after I clicked the toggle bar and closed it, it works smoothly.

But after I used the toggle bar and came back to the normal desktop view the top menu's width stays 0.

I don't want to refresh my page each and every time when I use both desktop and mobile view.

*ps: I've already seen many posts and nothing helped to fix my issue*

Here's my code snippet.

```js
   function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
```

```css
.menus{float:right;}
a{text-decoration:none!important;}
li{list-style:none; display:inline-block;}
   .toggle{display:none;}
a.closebtn{display:none;}
 .container
 {
 max-width:1180px; 
 margin:0 auto;
  }

@media screen and (max-width:767px)
{
.overlay {height: 100%; width: 0; position: fixed; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);    overflow-x: hidden; transition: 0.5s;}
.overlay-content {position: relative;  top: 13%;  width: 100%; text-align: center;  margin-top: 25px;}
.overlay a {padding: 5px 0; display: block; color:#fff; transition: 0.6s;}
.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {color:#f0c250;}
.overlay .closebtn {position: absolute;display:block; top: 20px;right: 45px;font-size: 40px;}
.toggle{display:block; margin:10px;}
.toggle span{background:#f0c250; padding:13px; border-radius:4px;}
.menus li{width:90px; margin:auto; display:block;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="logos col-sm-3">
<img src="images/logo1.png" alt="logo1">
</div>
    <div class="menus col-sm-9">
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; 
 </a>
 <div class="overlay-content">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>    
</ul></div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
 <span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to solve my problem?.
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: there is no `.overlay` style for desktop .. copy/paste the `.overlay` style to outside the media query and see what you'll get

Comment: The overlay class should be triggered only when the screen size is below 767px

Comment: @Vira I hope my answer helps you .. after using js to change your nav style it kept the inline style `width = 0%` you'll need a `resize` event to return the width again to 100% .. I think you can also try `width : 100% important;` for `myNav` above 767px screen ..

Comment: let me try this one @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: not working @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `element.classList.add("mystyle");` and `.remove()` and add a `.mystyle{width : 100%}` on `767px` screen

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
function openNav() {
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
}

function closeNav() {
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
}
```

```css
.menus{float:right;}
a{text-decoration:none!important;}
li{list-style:none; display:inline-block;}
   .toggle{display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width:767px)
{
.overlay {height: 100%; width: 0; position: fixed; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);    overflow-x: hidden; transition: 0.5s;}
.mystyle{width : 100%}
.overlay-content {position: relative;  top: 13%;  width: 100%; text-align: center;  margin-top: 25px;}
.overlay a {padding: 5px 0; display: block; color:#fff; transition: 0.6s;}
.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {color:#f0c250;}
.overlay .closebtn {position: absolute;display:block; top: 20px;right: 45px;font-size: 40px;}
.toggle{display:block; margin:10px;}
.toggle span{background:#f0c250; padding:13px; border-radius:4px;}
.menus li{width:90px; margin:auto; display:block;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="logos col-sm-3">
<img src="images/logo1.png" alt="logo1">
</div>
    <div class="menus col-sm-9">
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; 
 </a>
 <div class="overlay-content">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>    
</ul></div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
 <span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**Note**: if user open the nav below 767px screen and resize to above .. when he come back to 767px screen the nav will still shown .. if you need to close the nav anywhy when resizing below 767px you'll need to use

```
window.addEventListener('resize' , function(){
   if(screen.width <= 767){
      closeNav();
   }
});
```

Comment: @Viira you're totally welcome .. please read the note on the answer .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @Viira I don't know who .. but I voted you up .. good Luck :)